# Replace entire string using SED command in UNIX

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have below XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<refdataContent xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent file:///opt/orbitz/schemas/content/refdataContent/1/0/refdataContent.xsd' xmlns='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent'>

  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelPlacementMetagyType.PREMIUMPLACEMENT'><![CDATA[Premium Placement]]></entry>
  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelAvailability.AVAILABLE'><![CDATA[Available]]></entry>
</refdataContent>
```

Need to replace the XML header

```
<refdataContent xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent file:///opt/orbitz/schemas/content/refdataContent/1/0/refdataContent.xsd'xmlns='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent'> </refdataContent>
```

as 
`<properties></properties>` using the command `SED`

Help?

Comment: Why is it a requirement that you use sed? You should use a tool designed for XML instead.

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the name of the `refdataContent` tag to `properties`?

Comment: If it works well with the entire text, why do you want to use a regular expression? Regular expressions are only useful if you need some generalization (and possible only if some generalization is acceptable).

Comment: @TomFenech Yes i want to change the tag to refdatacontent using command `sed`

Answer (score 0):

What about `sed -i 's/refdataContent/properties/g' yourfile.xml` ?

Comment: I want to remove the entire line
`<refdataContent xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent file:///opt/orbitz/schemas/content/refdataContent/1/0/refdataContent.xsd'xmlns='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent'> </refdataContent>` with `<properties>`. Any way to find and replace using regex?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your question. Check 'Washington Guedes' answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do, I'll try a couple options.

given the following:

```
$ cat blah.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<refdataContent xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent file:///opt/orbitz/schemas/content/refdataContent/1/0/refdataContent.xsd' xmlns='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent'>

  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelPlacementMetagyType.PREMIUMPLACEMENT'><![CDATA[Premium Placement]]></entry>
  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelAvailability.AVAILABLE'><![CDATA[Available]]></entry>
</refdataContent>
```

If there is a unique string in the line that you want to delete, match that string and delete the line. Let's use `XMLSchema-instance`:

```
$ sed '/XMLSchema-instance/d' blah.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelPlacementMetagyType.PREMIUMPLACEMENT'><![CDATA[Premium Placement]]></entry>
  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelAvailability.AVAILABLE'><![CDATA[Available]]></entry>
</refdataContent>
```

to replace that line with `<properties></properties>`:

```
$ sed 's/.*XMLSchema-instance.*/<properties><\/properties>/g' blah.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<properties></properties>

  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelPlacementMetagyType.PREMIUMPLACEMENT'><![CDATA[Premium Placement]]></entry>
  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelAvailability.AVAILABLE'><![CDATA[Available]]></entry>
</refdataContent>
```

to wrap the line in `<properties></properties>`:

```
$ sed '/XMLSchema-instance/i\
> <properties>' blah.xml | sed '/XMLSchema-instance/a\
> </properties>'
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<properties><refdataContent xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent file:///opt/orbitz/schemas/content/refdataContent/1/0/refdataContent.xsd' xmlns='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent'>
</properties>
  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelPlacementMetagyType.PREMIUMPLACEMENT'><![CDATA[Premium Placement]]></entry>
  <entry key='com.orbitz.reference.api.hotel.HotelAvailability.AVAILABLE'><![CDATA[Available]]></entry>
</refdataContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean change

```
<refdataContent xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent file:///opt/orbitz/schemas/content/refdataContent/1/0/refdataContent.xsd'xmlns='http://www.orbitz.com/refdataContent'>
```

to `<properties>` and `</refdataContent>` to `</properties>`?

It can be done with `s/refdataContent.*/properties>/`.

And if you want to remove those `<entry></entry>` as well, use this:

```
/<refdataContent/,/<\/refdataContent/{s/refdataContent.*/properties>/p;d}
```